# Download file_get_contents response

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following jquery:

```
$(".download").click(function(){     
  $.post('get_bot.php', "url_code="+url_code, function (response) {
    alert(response);
  });
});
```

url_code is a variable that has the url for a json structure, here is a live example of the return:
https://services.sapo.pt/Codebits/botmake/01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,I%20Rule!

Those numbers are parameters to generate different images.

On my get_bot.php page I'm doing:

```
$urlc=$_POST['url_code'];
$bot = file_get_contents($urlc);
header("content-type: image/png");
echo $bot;
```

I'm looking into ways on how to get a response as a .png file download, so when the user clicks .download there is a download window prompt with the .png file.

Passing in a correct url and echoing the file_get_content results seems to work fine (although if I try to right click and save the image, it actually saves the php file...)

Any help with this would be great, I'm not very experienced with json structures, so far I've only dealt with array structures, never an image output.

I'm aware I'm probably way off here on getting an actual result, but any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you not use this URL directly when the PHP do nothing except return the URL content?

Comment: Why don't you redirect to the url? Use `header("Location: ".$urlc);` on second line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5) describes what you need to do. Basically, you need to add

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="fname.ext"
```

To the header if I'm not mistaken.

**EDIT**
Here is a sample script. I've confirmed that this works on two of my servers with different setups.

```
<?php
  header("content-type: image/jpg");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='pic.jpg'");
  readfile('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/');
?>
```

Comment: Just header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="picture.png"'); and echo $bot after? Not getting a file download response.

Comment: I just tested this, and it works for me. Make sure that if you use double quotes in `header("")` use single quotes around `filename=''` to prevent syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks, got it working by not using ajax at all, I just point the user to get_bot?bot=(numbers params here) and use $_GET to retrieve the parms.

Comment: Better to use [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) instead of file_get_contents... This eliminates possible memory issues. It also doesn't require the contents of the file to be read to a variable first.

Comment: @MartyMcVry You are right. I just jused `file_get_contents` to match OPs code. Edited my post anyway in case someone decides to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this function on your get_bot.php to start a download of a file instead of showing it in the browser (should work cross-browser):

```
function download($file, $path)
{
    $size = filesize($path.$file);

    @ob_end_clean();

    if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    header("Cache-control: no-cache, pre-check=0, post-check=0");
    header("Cache-control: private");
    header('Pragma: private');
    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");

    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
    {
        list($a, $range) = explode("=",$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'],2);
        list($range) = explode(",",$range,2);
        list($range, $range_end) = explode("-", $range);
        $range=intval($range);
        if(!$range_end) {
            $range_end=$size-1;
        } else {
            $range_end=intval($range_end);
        }

        $new_length = $range_end-$range+1;
        header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content");
        header("Content-Length: $new_length");
        header("Content-Range: bytes $range-$range_end/$size");
    } else {
        $new_length=$size;
        header("Content-Length: ".$size);
    }

    $chunksize = 1*(1024*1024);
    $bytes_send = 0;
    if ($file = fopen($path.$file, 'rb'))
    {
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
        fseek($file, $range);

        while
            (!feof($file) && 
             (!connection_aborted()) && 
             ($bytes_send<$new_length) )
        {
            $buffer = fread($file, $chunksize);
            print($buffer);
            flush();
            $bytes_send += strlen($buffer);
        }
    fclose($file);
    } else die('Error - can not open file.');

die();
}
```